# Xamarin Android How to record video in background and send it to server using FTP

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using Xamarin to create my app. I have already succeeded to code many functions. But i have a problem recording video function. Here is my code

```
    const string fileName = "MyTestVideos";

    void recordVideo()
    {

        string path = GetDir (fileName, FileCreationMode.WorldReadable) + "/myVid.mp4";

        video.StopPlayback ();
        if (recorder == null)
            recorder = new MediaRecorder ();
        else
            recorder.Reset ();

        recorder.SetVideoSource (VideoSource.Camera);
        recorder.SetAudioSource (AudioSource.Camcorder);
        recorder.SetProfile (CamcorderProfile.Get (CamcorderQuality.High));
        recorder.SetOrientationHint (90);
        recorder.SetOutputFile (path);
        recorder.SetPreviewDisplay (video.Holder.Surface);
        recorder.Prepare ();
        recorder.Start ();
    }
```

I want to record the video on background and then send it to server using FTP. And then delete the recorded video.I need help to do that. Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I do not know what might be wrong with the video recorder, but sending the resulting video file to the FTP server is easy with the help of Rebex FTP/SSL for .NET component - just add the trial version directly from [Xamarin Studio component store](https://components.xamarin.com/view/Rebex-Ftp) and use this code to upload the file:

```
// create FTP client instance
using (var ftp = new Rebex.Net.Ftp())
{
    // connect to your FTP server with the specified SslMode you need
    ftp.Connect("server", SslMode.Implicit);

    // authenticate
    ftp.Login(username, password);

    // upload a file
    ftp.PutFile("myVid.mp4", "/MyData/myVid.mp4");

    // disconnect (not required, but polite)
    ftp.Disconnect();
}
```

disclaimer - I work for Rebex.NET company.